# Eclipse is not compiling an .exe in Windows (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, mingw, libraries

I have done plenty of research on this and I cannot figure it out. I am on a team where we had all written our individual code and now, one of our team members is working on compiling all of our code as one file. My code will not allow him to compile an .exe. I have encountered the same issue. This had all worked for me in Code::Blocks; however, we are using Eclipse. We are using MinGW as the compiler and I have the PE64 Windows parser set as the binary parser.

I have replaced the Boost filesystem library with the C++17 filesystem library and unfortunately, the result is the same. In my troubleshooting process, I had created a hello, world program with all of the libraries that I am using included. In that case, the executable was not created. I had then removed all of the libraries that I am using. In that instance, an executable was created. I suspect that libcurl-x64.dll cannot be found in some regard and that that is why the executable will not be built. I have already looked for duplicate filenames in the include folders. None had existed. My build log is as follows:

```
19:34:27 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++ ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++17 "-IC:\\libraries5\\xlnt-master\\include" "-IC:\\libraries5\\curl-7.70.0-win64-mingw\\include" -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\thirdparty" -static -l -o Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe main.o 
g++: error: Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe: No such file or directory

19:34:29 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.26ms)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in getting an executable created. Thank you.

Edit: As was requested by Julian, I have uploaded my makefile.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3c11vnccjah3frx/makefile?dl=0

My full build log in Eclipse when using GNU Make is:

```
21:09:58 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++ ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++17 -I"C:\libraries5\xlnt-master\include" -I"C:\libraries5\curl-7.70.0-win64-mingw\include" -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp
 
Building target: Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe
Invoking: MinGW C++ Linker
g++ -L"C:\thirdparty" -static -l -o "Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe"  ./main.o   
g++.exe: error: Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe: No such file or directory
makefile:44: recipe for target 'Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe' failed
make: *** [Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a bit more information? Which libraries are you exactly using? Is Eclipse generating a Makefile (or some other file, that drives the build process)? If that's the case, can you upload it here?

With the informations you have provided so far, it's really hard to guess what the issue might be.

Comment: What seems strange to me, though, is the link command `-l` without a parameter

Comment: I am using xlnt found here: https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt.

I built it using the MinGW Makefiles generator in CMake. I have libxlnt.a in my "thirdparty" directory.

I am also using the latest 64-bit version of curl for Windows found here:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows/.

I have libcurl.a, libcurl.dll.a, and libcurl-x64.dll in my "thirdparty" directory.

No makefile is generated when using Eclipse's CDT Internal Builder, but when using GNU Make, a makefile is generated and I get the error `makefile:44: recipe for target 'Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe' failed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compilation issues, you can also use the [WSL terminal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RTSlby-l9w).

Once you install and set up your linux terminal, run these commands

```
$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install g++
$sudo apt install gcc
```

Change your directory into your eclipse working directory and run your g++ command.

Comment: Thank you. I'm making some progress, I hope. When I run my command as you had suggested, I get: 

`main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

There are no errors in Eclipse, though.

Comment: I think it's time for me to search for another solution. simple-mail on GitHub is looking promising. I was using curl to send an email. Thanks again for your help.

https://github.com/cutelyst/simple-mail

Comment: It's been a little bit of time, but our team had decided to move to Visual Studio and the vcpkg package manager. Using them, everything had worked. We hadn't used another solution in place of curl.